# Liquid Pixels check source image mime type

Tags: image, rendering, mime-types

unfortunately, I cannot tag this post with the correct "technology" because it does not exist and i dont have 1500 reputation to create it.

We are using a cloud service called "Liquid Pixels" to render some stuff on our images.

Lets say we have an image chain that is currently rendering a ribbon on the given JPEG image. This chain is working fine. 
Then I adapted the chain to work with animated gif images, therefore I changed the sink format to gif (sink=format[gif]). That was working fine as well.

Now I want to combine the two cases in one chain, because the only difference is the sink command. The plan is to check the MIME type of the source image and then either render a gif or a jpg image.

I rendered the image as xml to view the metadata map.
[image]

I thought i can do it like this.

```
source=url[https://something.com/1x1_sample.gif],name[testImage]

sink=format[gif],if[('testImage.format' eq 'GIF')]
sink=format[jpg],if[('testImage.format' ne 'GIF’)]
```

But for some reason I cannot access the format attribute. I am used to grab some parameters like “testImage.width” or “testImage.height”, but for some reason i cannot access the format=“GIF” property. I guess that has happens because the width and height are on a different hierarchy level in the metadata map.

I hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image does not actually have a "format" during the render. Only a file has a format. During processing the image is simply on memory as either raster or vector data; it is only when you sink that it becomes a file in whatever format. Also, LiquiFire OS uses the image data to determine the original format when acquiring an image from a source, never the image name itself.

If you need operations in your LiquiFire Image Chain to react to the source image URL, you can test the last part of the image name by applying a regular expression to see if it is either .GIF or .gif.  An example of how that can be done:

```
set=imageURL[https://your.server.com/sample.gif]
source=url[global.imageURL],name[testImage]
regexcase=name[isGif],key[global.imageURL],cases[\.gif$|\.GIF$|\.\w+$],values[yes|yes|no]
sink=format[gif],if[('global.isGif' eq 'yes')]
sink=format[jpg],if[('global.isGif' eq 'no’)]
```

Comment: In the end I checked if the source file has more than one frame, because our DAM system does not have a filetype ending like .gif for the original rendition